# Accordion menu bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this bootstrap menu and wanted to make it function as an accordion.

If you click on "main level" and its expanded, clicking on any other "main level" open would close the open one.

Here is a working example: http://www.bootply.com/HNSXXvcmZJ

```
$('.tree-toggle').click(function () {
$(this).parent().children('ul.tree').toggle();});$(function(){$('.tree-toggle').parent().children('ul.tree').toggle();})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap has its own accordion. Did you give it a try? http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion

Comment: @dalondon Give it a try and then if you're absolutely stuck ask another question

Comment: I did give it a try and it's not working for me as stated above.

Comment: Where is current menue? post the code please. And @Nelo_j this shouldn't be a anser.